# How to install Guest Additions with a Oracle Gnu/Linux guest on VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, oracle-vm-server

I have a Linux virtual box and want to install Guest Additions. I've successfully mounted the iso. But now what...?

How can I access the mounted cd-rom in the terminal of the virtual machine as to install Guest Additions?

When I `cd media` then `ls` returns empty.

[image]

Comment: You say in the title that the guest is MS Windows 10, however in the images it shows the guest as Oracle Gnu/Linux. Can you clarify you question.

Comment: Thnx @ctrl-alt-delor, I've updated the title. I was thinking of my own pc as the guest.

Comment: Either the directory is wrong or the iso is not mounted. What's the output of `mount | grep iso`? You can try to mount it manually, on my guest (no oracle) commands `cd /; mount /dev/sr0 /media; cd /media` work (replace `/dev/sr0` with your virtual cdrom device).

Comment: Thanks @Freddy. `mount | grep iso` doesn't return anything (just like the last `ls` in the image doesn't return anything). How do I know what to replace `/dev/sr0` with? How do I know where I can find my virtual cdrom?

Comment: @Marty On my guest the last line of `dmesg | grep -i cd-rom` shows me `[    2.852493] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0`. Note the last `sr0` for the device name. But I don't know if this works on your oracle guest.

Comment: Yes! `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Comment: Please be so kind and write your own answer. I think you can accept it after 48 hours.

Comment: Thnx @Freddy, I haven't been able to get it to work just yet. I've added an update to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added *Internet connectivity* following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47272983):

```
Check connectivity: `sudo nmcli d`
If disconnected: `sudo nmtui` > Edit a connection, select network interface and choose "Automatically connect".
`sudo reboot now`
Test: `ping www.google.com`
```

I added *bzip2*: `yum install bzip2`

I also added *GNOME GUI Desktop*, according to [these](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=74463) instructions:

```
yum group list
yum groupinstall 'Server with GUI'
systemctl enable graphical.target --force
Rebooted the Guest OS Oracle Linux 7.1
gnome-shell --version
```

Next, to *mount* in the media folder, I entered:

```
cd /;
mount /dev/sr0 /media;
cd /media
ls
```

This returns various files including VBoxLinuxAdditions.run. I ran `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`, which returned "Kernel headers not found for target kernel":

[image]

`uname -r` and `rpm -q kernel-devel` indeed show different versions.

`yum install kernel-headers-$(uname -r) kernel-devel-$(uname -r)` couldn't find the packages. I then ran `yum distro-sync` in the hope to synchronize the versions. But there were still 2 different versions.

However, booting up the VM there now was a new option available: "Oracle Linux Server 7.6, with Linux 3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64" rather than "Oracle Linux Server (4.14.35-1818.3.3.el7uek.x86_64 with Unbreakable Ent" that I normally selected the virtual box boot menu.

I choose this option and kernel-headers and kernel-devel now were the same versions! `yum install kernel-headers-$(uname -r) kernel-devel-$(uname -r)` returned "already installed and latest version". It was using the same versions, so that was no longer the problem.

But `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` now returned "This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules. Please install the gcc make perl packages from your distribution.".

I ran `yum install build-essential gcc make perl dkms`. And then after `sudo reboot now` it successfully installed Guest Additions!